# Swift and Obj-c Interoperability issues while unit testing

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have an iOS application written in Obj-C which has unit tests defined as well. Now, i am adding a new feature where i am using a swift class (S) in an Obj-C class(O). I have the bridging header in place for both the main target and the test target. Till this point everything works really well.

Here's the problem, 
If i want to create an unit test class(U) for class O in swift and run it, i get an issue saying bridging header not found. I am assuming this is because O uses S and these details are in the bridging header file and then again i am trying to use both S and O in U resulting the failure. If i add any other Obj-C class which doesn't use S, it works perfectly fine.

Here's what i have already done just make sure you know whats happening, 
I have a forward declaration in O.h for class S because i know the O.h file will not support holding the -Swift.h import statement and hence it is in O.m file.

Is this scenario supported?

```
Class O uses Class S. 
Class U can test class O by using class S. 

Note: O->Objective-C
      S->Swift Class
      U->Unit test class in swift.
```

Comment: `I have the bridging header in place for both the main target and the test target` in which you're importing the main application's bridging header inside the unit test's bridging header,  right? Maybe add this to the question details if so?

Comment: IIRC, Apple recommends you write unit tests in the same language as the class they're testing. In this case, I'd likely write the unit tests in Objective C since the class they're testing is in Objective-C. That is, it's not significant that it uses a Swift class.

Comment: However, what issue are you actually _seeing_? Or why do you suspect it _isn't_ supported?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was simple but not very evident. I had to place the import statements in the bridging header files in the order of the usage. For example: if one class has dependency on the other, then its important that you place the dependency's import statement first and then the calling class' file in the bridging header